# Why Safari is consuming so much battery?

Tags: iphone, safari, battery

From last 2-3 weeks I started noticing that my iPhone is consuming more battery than usual, around two to three times more.  When I looked at battery consumption details I found out that Safari is consuming too much battery. And this is happening consistently from last 2-3 weeks when I don't even use safari very much. As an example take a look at image attached, for 12 minutes of screen time it consumed 73% of battery. Why?

iOS version: 9.2.1

Phone: iPhone 6

Safari: latest available version

[image: battery consumption stats]

Comment: How many tabs do you have open? One time I had this issue but I also have something crazy like 30 tabs open

Comment: @iSkore not many, I always try to close all the tabs and also I try not to keep Safari running in the background. I am not a heavy mobile user.

Comment: Hmm. Then my guess is to close all apps and hard restart you phone. Hold down home and power buttons until the screen goes blank, then release the home button. You should see the apple symbol with a loading bar.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, even after I clean-install the iPhone. I suspect it may be a hardware issue, and the battery drain is attributed to Safari in calculations even though it's not the prime culprit.

Comment: Do you have any "content blockers" installed? You can check in Settings > Safari > Content Blockers.

Comment: No. *of the battery usage* Safari is 73% to blame. Safari did not use 73% of your battery in 12 minutes.

Comment: Also "latest available version" doesn't tell us anything as the days and weeks and months go by and this question persists in the archive.

Comment: Answers are not really answering the problem. My brand new iOS 11 phone is burning battery like crazy and Safari's percentage (in the last 24 hours view) is increasing even though I'm not using it!

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem for the first after updating my iPhone 6s to iOS 11. I wasn't using Safari as I use Chrome but it would consume up to 50% of my battery and I was having to charge more frequently then before.

The solution was to disable iCloud syncing for Safari:
**Settings → Apple ID → iCloud and turn off Safari.**

My phone is now behaving 'normally'.

Answer (score 2):

That's not total battery used, it's the percentage of battery used out of all battery used for the last 4 days. So you started out with 100% battery on monday and on friday you had 80% left. If safari is listed as 74%, then that means about 15% of the 20% was used by safari.

Comment: True, but the OP says that he wasn't using Safari hardly at all.

Answer (score 1):

12 minutes in 4 days - but keep in mind other apps may pull up a Safari view, and iOS may be counting that depending on the method the apps use to do it.

Twitter and Mail are two likely culprits there.

Comment: If Twitter displays web content in a WebView within the Twitter app, that does not count as Safari use, which is the most common case for web content on Twitter.